# save innerHtml to a list of strings

Tags: c#, list

I got this code where btag is a list of urls:

```
foreach (var link in bTags)
            {
                HtmlDocument htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load(link);

                var listOfTitles = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='view-subject']//h1")
                    .Select(o => o.InnerText).ToString();

                //Code to save the node to a list of string

            }
```

I also got this class:

```
 public class Job
    {
        public Job()
        {
            Desc = new list<string>();

            JobTitle = new List<string>();
        }
        public List<string> Desc { get; set; }

        public List<string> JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I intend to create a job-object by looping through my `btags`, picking the appropriate nodes. The foreach picks out all the JobTitles in my document, but how do I save these values to my Job-object?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
List<string> listOfTitles = new List<string>();
            foreach (var link in bTags)
            {
                HtmlDocument htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load(link);
                //NOTE!: You want to set the o.InnerText to string, not the resulting list. (ive done that in this example)
                var titlesFromCurrentLink = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='view-subject']//h1").Select(o => o.InnerText.ToString());
                listOfTitles.AddRange(titlesFromCurrentLink);
            }

            foreach(var title in listOfTitles)
            {
                Job newJob = new Job()
                {
                    JobTitle = title;
                };
            }
```

I get an error on the:

```
JobTitle = title;
```

It says:Cannot convert source-type "string" to target type "system.collection.geneic.list"

Comment: A clarification - An instance of a Job has many job titles - is this correct? And does this list of job titles for a particular job depend on a particular "link"?

Comment: Aha! This error is very indicative of my previous comment. In your Job class you have "List<string> JobTitle", The name makes me think it should be one title, but the list indicates otherwise. Which should it be?

Comment: In the end i would like to pass a list of job-objects to my view. Each job-object will contain 1 link, 1 title...and maybe some more properties...So I guess the JobTitle should not be a list after all?

Comment: Alright. My answer guessed the other way. Let me update it. You'll find that these errors sometimes occur because you haven't yet figured out __exactly__ what you want to do. Its good to reflect on exactly what you want and make sure the code reflects your desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a result of a list of Job objects, where one job is created per link, and each job has a single job title, your main issue was with the line:

```
var listOfTitles = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='view-subject']//h1")
                    .Select(o => o.InnerText).ToString();
```

That `.Select()` will return a list of innerTexts from the nodes (`SelectNodes`) you've selected. 
What you really want is a single title, and to use that title when creating a job. Which looks more like:

```
var titleNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='view-subject']//h1").FirstOrDefault();
```

At this point it's good to check you actually have a title worth getting - The `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if there weren't any results.

```
if( titleNode != null )
{
    string titleText = titleNode.InnerText;
    Job currentJob = new Job()
    {
        JobTitle = titleText
    };
}
```

Additionally you want to change your `Job` class `Desc` and `JobTitle` properties to be strings rather than `List<string>`:

```
public class Job
{
...
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, Im a bit confused though, you are saying that I should do another foreach inside my current foreach?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends whether the titles are directly related to the current link. Ill update the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the titles and the links should be related.

Comment: Thans again, the way you name things makes it much more easy to read, I still get an error though, please see update if you can..

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help!
I can now see that I can create a new job-object in the foreach, then in the end I pass these objects as a list! Thank you!